# Chart and dashboard data refresh in Ui apps

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization

When you change the values that a chart is tied to in Sheets the chart automatically updates / refreshes with the new data.  Is there a way to replicate this behavior with Ui apps that are displaying a dashboard or chart?  I know you can just refresh the browser or rebuild the entire chart / dashboard with a server function and timer.

Answer (score 0):

No. Only charts within a spreadsheet refresh instantly.