# set 'refreshInterval' for Charts in Google Apps Script

Tags: user-interface, web-applications, charts, google-apps-script

I'm a math teacher, not a programmer so you'll have to forgive my ignorance here...

I've been looking all over for a way to set the chart options in a web app written in **Google Apps Script** from the `doGet()` function without any action from the user of the app. I've found documentation in the visualization language but nothing for charts. Here is what I'm thinking should work (but doesn't).

```
var Correct = Charts.newPieChart().setOption("refreshInterval", 1)
    .setDataTable(dataTable3)
    .setTitle("% Correct").setDimensions(400, 300).set3D()
    .build();
```

I have the app return the graph just fine but when I update the data on the referenced spreadsheet it will only update the chart if I refresh the page the chart is in manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rebuild the entire chart on a timer...

```
function doGet() {
  // Build chart
  // Add timer
  app.addTimer(app.createServerHandler("refresh") , 3000);  // 3 secs
}

function refresh(e) {
  // Clear panel that contains chart
  panel.clear();
  // Re-build chart
  // Add timer again 
  app.addTimer(app.createServerHandler("refresh") , 3000);
}
```

It's not the exact same as how charts inside of sheets refresh that [I was looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995827/chart-and-dashboard-data-refresh-in-ui-apps) as well, but there's no manual page refresh with this.

Comment: What if I set a data URL instead of getting it through a spreadsheet app call? I found last night in the charts API there is a setUrl function and was going to give that a try this weekend. Will use your other solution if that doesn't work--thanks. Will the 5 minute script limit stop the refresh or will it run indefinitely?

Comment: .setDataUrl doesn't seem to work as I had hoped. The charts I have are within a dashboard panel and it seems to break if I clear just the chart and not the category filters. So it doesn't appear glitchy while in use I am using your suggestion to add a manual refresh button. Thank you so much for your help--this was great!

Comment: If you're using a dashboard, you'll have to rebuild / refresh the entire dashboard.  I didn't think about the 5 min timeout, did it stop for you?

Comment: Didn't let it go that long. With dashboard controls I didn't want them to reset while changing views--that's why I'm going with manual refresh now.